# gravar arquivo json no banco de dados

Tags: javascript, sql, json

é uma boa idéia?

estava pensando em fazer um projeto aonde o usuário irá criar vários elementos dinamicamente (tabelas, escolher uma determinada opção, preencher etc), estes elementos gerados dinamicamente deverão ser salvas no banco para posteriormente serem atualizadas, modificadas (algo semelhante ao `jsfiddle`, onde você dar um update em um projeto já existente, modificar, etc).

Como normalmente os desenvolvedores fazem? gravam o json no banco? depois lêêm ele e vão gerando e preenchendo os elementos no html?

```
{["firstName":{"required":"true","type":"text"},"lastName":{"required":"true","type":"text"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não só pode, como é uma prática comum e recomendada para esse tipo de situação. Além disso os dados salvos podem vir a ser usados por qualquer linguagem e framework, já que JSON é universalmente entendido.

Por exemplo, passando o Json para seu frontend, com Javascript você cria os campos. Você pode também usar o Json e gerar o HTML com PHP. Você pode até mesmo usar o JSON e gerar uma tela para uma App iPhone, com Swift. E assim vai.

É tão aceitável, que os principais RDBMS possuem estruturas internas para JSON:

- PostgreSQL possui um tipo nativo json e jsonb com diversas funções utilitárias para tratar JSON: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html
- O MySQL 5.7.7 também adicionou o tipo JSON: http://mysqlserverteam.com/json-labs-release-native-json-data-type-and-binary-format/

Bancos noSQL são puramente Json:

> CouchDB, é um banco de dados de código-aberto que foca na facilidade de uso e na filosofia de ser "um banco de dados que abrange a Web"1 . É um banco de dados não-relacional (NoSQL) que **usa JSON para armazenar os dados**, JavaScript como sua linguagem de consulta https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB